# How to handle promises as they resolve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise, es6-promise

Currently, this code print out a zero, because the first promise in the array resolves immediately.

```js
const promises = [];
const promiser = (number) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => window.setTimeout(() => resolve(number), number * 100));
for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
  const promise = promiser(index);
  promises.push(promise);
}

Promise.race(promises).then(r => console.debug(r));
```

I'm looking to make it so that once the quickest promise resolves, it is removed from the `promises` array and a new `Promise.race` call is made with the remaining promises, repeating until no promise is left.

Since `Promise.race` returns the result of the promise, not the resolved promise itself, though, I am unable to identify which promise was it that resolved and I do not know which one to remove from the array. Is there a way to know this? I suppose I could return a complex object with some sort of a correlation key and the result, but that seems weird. I was hoping second parameter of the `Promise.race` callback would be index of the promise, but that's not the case and it doesn't make sense either since the `then` is just a `then` of another promise, so how would it know that it should return some index anyway. Can you think of a better way?

Also, I run all the promises with the first `race`, but that shouldn't be a problem for subsequent `race`s, right? In case another promise resolved in the meantime before the subsequent `race` call was made, it should just return it, no problem, correct? And if multiple promises did resolve in the meantime, it would just return the first (in array order or in resolution order?) and then the next `race` would return the second and so on… Right?

BTW I also though I could walk the array and remove promises that have `isResolved`, but that's not a real thing. Even if it was, though, this would completely break for the case where multiple promises resolve between the calls to `race`.

Comment: could you make the Promises resolve to a value that identifies the promise, as well as the value you are after - in the case of your example, your value is the index, so it's quite trivial to do what you want with that code

Comment: Promise.race() is used when you only care about one of the resolutions.
- For sequential execution, just add .then() clauses to a single promise, you can also return a promise in .then
- For parallel execution, use Promise.all as in Mattias Buelens answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an identifier to the promises

```
const promises = [];
const promiser = (number, id) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => window.setTimeout(() => resolve({ number, id }), number * 100));
for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
  const promise = promiser(index, "id_" + index);
  promises.push(promise);
}

Promise.race(promises).then(r => console.debug(r.id));
```

Anyway if you are working with a promise library such as [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) you can find some utility that can help you structure your code better ( like `Promise.reduce` or `Promise.any` )

Comment: Thanks, so basically what I said in the middle paragraph. This sucks because I can't use this with promises I don't create. I'll look into Bluebird to see if it suits my needs.

Comment: You can use it with promises you don't create, by use of something along the lines of `.then(r => ({result:r, id:someIdentifier}))` - and that's the promise you put in the array

Comment: Good point! BTW @drinchev Bluebird seems to be running both `each` and `reduce` sequentially which sucks, because for me it doesn't matter in which order the promises resolve, I need to process each as soon as it does. But the trick with ID you and @Jaromanda X proposed will work for me, thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm looking to make it so that once the quickest promise resolves, it is removed from the `promises` array and a new `Promise.race` call is made with the remaining promises, repeating until no promise is left.

Why do you want to use `Promise.race` if you eventually want to handle *all* promises? Can't you simply process every promise as soon as it resolves, and then wait until all promises have been processed?

```
const promises = [];
const promiser = (number) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => window.setTimeout(() => resolve(number), number * 100));

for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
  const promise = promiser(index)
      .then(r => process(r)); // process every promise individually
  promises.push(promise);
}

Promise.all(promises) // wait for all promises to be processed
       .then(r => console.debug('all done!'));
```

Or is `process` *also* asynchronous, and you need to ensure that only one promise is getting processed at a time?

Comment: Initially, I wanted `process` be asynchronous as well so yeah, but as I'm looking into my problem further, turns out I'll be able to do without it, so you are actually right! I'll keep @drinchev's answer marked as they answered my question, if you don't mind, but you helped me see I was asking the wrong question. Thank you.

Comment: This is the right answer.
 - The 3 lines in the for loop should be a single push expression
 - A .catch should be added to the end of Promise.all().then() that gets the first reject or exception.